# how to set my odoo app store in debug mode?

Tags: python, odoo

Tried:

setting to debug mode in odoo

show error:

Traceback:

Error: Invalid Prop 'apps' in component 'HomeMenu'
at Object.QWeb.utils.validateProps (http://0.0.0.0:9069/web/content/838-859cfb0/web.assets_common.js:1173:20)
at new Component (http://0.0.0.0:9069/web/content/838-859cfb0/web.assets_common.js:1198:42)
at new HomeMenu (http://0.0.0.0:9069/web/content/839-da53f17/web.assets_backend.js:3324:257)
at QWeb.eval (eval at _compile (http://0.0.0.0:9069/web/content/838-859cfb0/web.assets_common.js:961:178), :57:19)
at QWeb.fn (http://0.0.0.0:9069/web/content/838-859cfb0/web.assets_common.js:943:178)
at QWeb.render (http://0.0.0.0:9069/web/content/838-859cfb0/web.assets_common.js:950:20)
at HomeMenuWrapper.__render (http://0.0.0.0:9069/web/content/838-859cfb0/web.assets_common.js:1262:33)
at HomeMenuWrapper.__prepareAndRender (http://0.0.0.0:9069/web/content/838-859cfb0/web.assets_common.js:1260:29)

Answer (score 0):

This is Javascript files loading issue. You can try debug mode on after upgrading web module of Odoo.